# EF Core - An error occurred while retrieving Mandate reports. System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Mandate>()

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am performing query and search filter in ASP.NET Core using Entity Framework.

I have this code:

`MandateApprovalStatus` - in the db model:

```
public MandateApprovalStatus MandateApprovalStatus { get; set; }
```

and in the enum:

```
 public enum MandateApprovalStatus : byte
        {
            [Description("Pending Approval")]
            PendingApproval = 0,
            Declined = 1,
            Approved = 2
        }
```

Repository:

```
    public IQueryable<Mandate> GetAllMandateAsync(PagingFilter filter)
    {
        try
        {
            IQueryable<Mandate> query = _dbContext.Mandates
                        .Include(x => x.MandateDetails)
                        .Include(x => x.MandateApproval)
                        .Include(x => x.Merchant)
                        .Include(x => x.BankBranch);



            // Apply search filtering
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.SearchQuery))
            {
                query = query
                    .Where(m =>
                    m.Merchant.MerchantName.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower()) ||
                    m.ReferenceNumber.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower()) ||
                    m.DrAccountNumber.Contains(filter.SearchQuery) ||
                    m.BankBranch.BranchName.ToLower().Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower()) ||
                    m.Amount.ToString().Contains(filter.SearchQuery) ||
                    m.MandateApprovalStatus.ToString().Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower()));
            }



            // Apply date range filtering
            if (filter.StartDate.HasValue && filter.EndDate.HasValue)
            {
                query = query.Where(m => m.CreatedAt >= filter.StartDate.Value && m.CreatedAt <= filter.EndDate.Value);
            }



            // Apply sorting
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.SortBy))
            {
                switch (filter.SortBy)
                {
                    case "MerchantName":
                        query = filter.IsSortAscending ? query.OrderBy(m => m.Merchant.MerchantName) : query.OrderByDescending(m => m.Merchant.MerchantName);
                        break;
                    case "ReferenceNumber":
                        query = filter.IsSortAscending ? query.OrderBy(m => m.ReferenceNumber) : query.OrderByDescending(m => m.ReferenceNumber);
                        break;
                    case "DrAccountNumber":
                        query = filter.IsSortAscending ? query.OrderBy(m => m.DrAccountNumber) : query.OrderByDescending(m => m.DrAccountNumber);
                        break;
                    case "BranchName":
                        query = filter.IsSortAscending ? query.OrderBy(m => m.BankBranch.BranchName) : query.OrderByDescending(m => m.BankBranch.BranchName);
                        break;
                    case "Amount":
                        query = filter.IsSortAscending ? query.OrderBy(m => m.Amount) : query.OrderByDescending(m => m.Amount);
                        break;
                    case "MandateApprovalStatus":
                        query = filter.IsSortAscending ? query.OrderBy(m => m.MandateApprovalStatus) : query.OrderByDescending(m => m.MandateApprovalStatus);
                        break;
                    case "CreatedAt":
                        query = filter.IsSortAscending ? query.OrderBy(m => m.CreatedAt) : query.OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedAt);
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Default sorting by CreatedAt in descending order
                query = query.OrderByDescending(m => m.CreatedAt);
            }

            return query;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex, "An error occurred while retrieving Mandates.");
            // Handle or log the exception as per your requirement
            throw new Exception("An error occurred while retrieving Mandates.", ex);
        }
    }
```

Then I applied this in the service:

```
   public async Task<Response<PageResult<IEnumerable<AdminMandateListDto>>>> GetAllMandateAsync(PagingFilter filter)
    {
        try
        {
            var query = _unitOfWork.AdminMandates.GetAllMandateAsync(filter);
           // var query = _unitOfWork.AdminMandates.GetAllMandateAsync(filter).ToList();



            var totalRecords = await query.CountAsync();
            var item = await query.PaginationAsync<Mandate, AdminMandateListDto>(filter.PageNumber, filter.PageSize, _mapper);



            var pageResult = new PageResult<IEnumerable<AdminMandateListDto>>
            {
                PageItems = item.PageItems,  // Update this line
                CurrentPage = filter.PageNumber,
                PageSize = filter.PageSize,
                NumberOfPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalRecords / filter.PageSize),
                TotalRecord = totalRecords
            };



            return new Response<PageResult<IEnumerable<AdminMandateListDto>>>()
            {
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Successful = true,
                Data = pageResult,
                Message = "All Mandates Retrieved Successfully"
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex, "An error occurred while retrieving Mandate reports.");
            return new Response<PageResult<IEnumerable<AdminMandateListDto>>>()
            {
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                Successful = false,
                Message = "An error occurred while retrieving Mandate reports."
            };
        }
    }
```

However, I got this error:

> [ERR] An error occurred while retrieving Mandate reports.
> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Join(
> inner: DbSet(),
> outerKeySelector: m => EF.Property<Guid?>(m, "MerchantId"),
> innerKeySelector: m0 => EF.Property<Guid?>(m0, "Id"),
> resultSelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<Mandate, Merchant>(
> Outer = o,
> Inner = i
> ))
> .LeftJoin(
> inner: DbSet(),
> outerKeySelector: m => EF.Property<Guid?>(m.Outer, "BankBranchId"),
> innerKeySelector: b => EF.Property<Guid?>(b, "Id"),
> resultSelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<Mandate, Merchant>, BankBranch>(
> Outer = o,
> Inner = i
> ))
> .Where(m => m.Outer.Inner.MerchantName.ToLower().Contains(__filter_SearchQuery_0) || m.Outer.Outer.ReferenceNumber.ToLower().Contains(__filter_SearchQuery_0) || m.Outer.Outer.DrAccountNumber.Contains(__filter_SearchQuery_0) || m.Inner.BranchName.ToLower().Contains(__filter_SearchQuery_0) || m.Outer.Outer.Amount.ToString().Contains(__filter_SearchQuery_0) || m.Outer.Outer.MandateApprovalStatus.ToString().Contains(__filter_SearchQuery_0))' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'object.ToString' failed. If this method can be mapped to your custom function, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2132413 for more information. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.g__CheckTranslated|15_0(ShapedQueryExpression translated, <>c__DisplayClass15_0& )
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
> at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
> at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
> at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
> at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
> at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
> at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.CountAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at AdminMandatesService.GetAllMandateAsync(PagingFilter filter) in:line 83

and this is line 83:

```
var totalRecords = await query.CountAsync();
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What is `MandateApprovalStatus`? Entity Framework is complaining that you are calling `ToString()` on this property, and it doesn't know how to translate that to SQL

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson - in tthe model:  public MandateApprovalStatus MandateApprovalStatus { get; set; }  and in the enum:         
 public enum MandateApprovalStatus : byte
        {
            [Description("Pending Approval")]
            PendingApproval = 0,
            Declined = 1,
            Approved = 2
        }

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson - See the updated code for MandateApprovalStatus

Comment: Did you read the error? The error complains about `ToString()` which simply makes no sense in SQL. LINQ queries don't run in the database, they get translated to SQL. The query has a *lot* of serious problems too, like all those calls to `ToLower()`. These are *not* necessary if the database uses case-*in*sensitive collation. They seriously harm performance too, because they prevent the server using any indexes constructed using the stored values. All those `ToLower()` calls will force the database to scan the entire table for matches

Comment: `String.Contains` is very expensive too. It translates to `LIKE '%blah%'` which can't use indexes. `LIKE 'blah%'` is essentially a range search though, which *can* use indexes. That's why most search forms only use `Starts With`. You should use `StartsWith` whenever possible

Comment: If you want to search for everything everywhere, consider using your database's full text search functionality to perform a Google-like search. *Don't* expect to just search numbers as if they were text though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably EF Core cannot convert `m.MandateApprovalStatus.ToString()`

You can replace `ToString` by conditional operator:

```cs
(m.MandateApprovalStatus == MandateApprovalStatus.PendingApproval ? "pending approval"
  : m.MandateApprovalStatus == MandateApprovalStatus.Declined ? "declined"
  : m.MandateApprovalStatus == MandateApprovalStatus.Approved ? "approved"
  : "unknown"
  ).Contains(filter.SearchQuery.ToLower()))
```